# Kafka how to set producer retries to Infinity

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How can I set the spring-boot property : spring.kafka.producer.retries to Integer.MAX_VALUE ?

Is it working to unset this property or this will default to 0 ?

@See default kafka in KIP
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) it defaults to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (at least with the current version), which concurs with the KIP.

Answer (score 2):

By default it is `2147483647` which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you can set between `[0,...,2147483647]`

**retries** [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#retries)

> Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error. Allowing retries without setting `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first. **Note additionally that produce requests will be failed before the number of retries has been exhausted if the timeout configured by `delivery.timeout.ms` expires first before successful acknowledgement.** Users should generally prefer to leave this config unset and instead use 1delivery.timeout.ms1 to control retry behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Default value of `ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG` is `2147483647`. Hope not defining the retries property will take care default value